# Testing whether a value matches a list of values

Tags: r, syntax, equality

This seems really obvious, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

I have a two columns (Col1, Col2). I want to check each row of Col1 for a match with a few keywords and if I find a match, write something into Col2. I'm doing it like this:

```
df$Col2[df$Col1=="Bob"]<-"Boy's name"
```

The problem I have is that I have lots of different names to check, so I'm ending up with a huge statement along the lines of:

```
df$Col2[df$Col1=="Bob" | df$Col1=="Tom" | df$Col1=="Dick" | df$Col1=="Harry"]<-"Boy's name"
```

I'd prefer to do this:

```
df$Col2[df$Col1=="Bob|Tom|Dick|Harry"]<-"Boy's name"
```

The above statement runs without an error, but it doesn't work either: it doesn't write anything to COl2. I'm guessing that it's not correctly evaluating the "Bob|Tom|Dick|Harry" bit. What am I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are looking for `%in%`. Something like this `df$Col2[df$Col1 %in% c("Bob", "Tom", "Dick", "Harry")] <- "Boy's name"`

Comment: Or `df$Col2[grep(paste(c('Bob', 'Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', collapse='|'), df$Col1)] <- "Boy's name"`

Comment: Thanks! It was the %in% bit that I didn't know about. I tried it, and it works.

Answer (score 4):

as suggested by @dickoa you can use the `%in%` keyword , you can do the following

```
condition <- df$col1 %in% c("Bob" , "Tom" , "Dick" , "Harry")

df$col2[condition] <- "Boy's name"
```

- **How it works**

for the first line `condition <- df$col1 %in% c("Bob" , "Tom" , "Dick" , "Harry")` it will check every value in `df$col1` if it matches any of the following names `Bob" , "Tom" , "Dick" , "Harry`
and if it finds a match it will return `True` and if it didn't it will return  `false` .
so the result now will be a vector of values of `True` and `false`.

when you pass the resulting vector as index to `df$col2` it will give only the values in `df$col2` that matches values of `True` and ignore `false` values , so now you can edit these values